# The expected output does not appear properly

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I was doing a hacker rank problem related to "Dictionaries and Maps" https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps I came up with a solution but the expected result does not appear properly. I have to press the return key in order to get the last output.
Below is the piece of code i came up for the problem.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args){

    int noOfQueries;
    String key;
    String value;
    String searchValue;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    noOfQueries = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfQueries; i++) {
        key = scan.next();
        value = scan.next();
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    while(scan.hasNext()){
        searchValue = scan.next();
        if(map.containsKey(searchValue)){
            System.out.println(searchValue + "=" + map.get(searchValue));
        }else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }

    }
}
}
```

**Sample inputs and outputs :** [Refer image for sample inputs and outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYVAg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code to run it on hackerrank and all my test cases passed succesfully. I assume you are facing this problem when running it on Eclipse or other IDE. Since you have a `scan.hasNext()` method in a while loop, the method will keep on looping infinitely and if you exhaust all your queries, there is no way your program knows that you are done entering all the queries. On Hackerrank that's different because they have the input in a file, which ultimately has an end and the `scan.hasNext()` will catch that and exit.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh, I was running it on Eclipse :)